# Dimple TooltipText EventHandler Issue

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm trying to figure out why `e.yValue` returns `null` in the `TooltipText` but returns the proper string value (y-axis is categorical) when using `EventHandler` and `console.log`

```
    var series3 = chart3.addSeries("finaid", dimple.plot.pie);
    series3.getTooltipText = function (e) {
        return [
            "Inst: " + e.yValue
            //"# of Students: " + e.zValue*1000
        ]
    }
    series3.addEventHandler("click", function (e) {
        console.log(e.yValue);
    })
```

e.zValue works as expected.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [eventArgs in dimple.js appear incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258732/eventargs-in-dimple-js-appear-incomplete)

`e.y` returns the appropriate string